# why is the terminal command not executing from java but is being executed when i directly copy it into the terminal?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, terminal, microservices

```
  @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void runAfterStartup() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Yaaah, I am running........");


        String command = "curl localhost:8081/actuator/refresh -d {} -H \"Content-Type: application/json\"";

        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

        // Read the output

        BufferedReader reader =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.print(line + "\n");
        }

        proc.waitFor();
    }
```

The above code doesnt work when i run it throws the error:

```
{"timestamp":"2022-06-21T07:54:37.951+00:00","status":415,"error":"Unsupported Media Type","path":"/actuator/refresh"}
```

However when i go to the terminal and hit the same command it works :

```
$ curl localhost:8081/actuator/refresh -d {} -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

Can someone help me out with this or give me a workaround where I can hit the /actuator/refresh via Java code and not through postman or terminal?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to run curl command from a java program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68937711/unable-to-run-curl-command-from-a-java-program)

Comment: ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("curl", "localhost:8081/actuator/refresh", "-d",
                "-H", "Content-Type: application/json");        is this the format to be used or how do you convert it?

Comment: Pinkman: almost; you need a value after the `-d` flag: `...,"-d","{}","-H",...`